# Passing CuPy array through scipy low pass filter

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, cupy

I want to send some data through a scipy built-in low pass filter. I was testing it out with some numpy arrays of data below. It works fine and outputs the filtered values when using numpy. I then wanted to see if I can use the GPU and speed things up and heard about CuPy which works similar to numpy. However, when I replace the numpy array with a cupy array, I get the following error `ValueError: could not convert b, a, and x to a common type`

```
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter, freqz
import cupy as cp
import time
import numpy as np

def butter_lowpass(cutoff, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    normal_cutoff = cutoff / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, normal_cutoff, btype='low', analog=False)
    return b, a

def butter_lowpass_filter(data, cutoff, fs, order=5):
    b, a = butter_lowpass(cutoff, fs, order=order)
    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y

order = 1
fs = 30.0       
cutoff = 0.3 

new_frame_np = np.ones(100)*3
new_frame_cp = cp.ones(100)*3

y = butter_lowpass_filter(new_frame_np, cutoff, fs, order) #WORKS
y = butter_lowpass_filter(new_frame_cp, cutoff, fs, order) #DOES NOT WORK
```

How can I make cupy arrays work in the above example?

Scipy seems to work with CPU tasks, so maybe it can't work with GPU cupy arrays. I wasnt able to find any library providing a low pass or band pass filter for cupy arrays.

Comment: You cannot use GPU arrays with scipy.signal. For GPU based signal processing, you should look at cuSignal or torch.audio (pytorch)

Comment: I looked through cuSignal and just to confirm, the firwin() is what can do the filtering right? There wasnt anything explicitly called lowpass filter

Answer (score 4):

I'm the creator of cuSignal. We spent some time in the past trying to GPU-accelerate SciPy's `lfilter`, but for ARMA filters, lfilter uses the DF-II form that has a data dependency that makes parallelization difficult. There are ways around this (e.g. parallelization via number of signals filtered at once), but we ended up calling this 'blocked'.

That said, we *do* have FIR filter support via the FFT method. This is essentially the same as `fftconvolve`, but it's wrapped as `cusignal.firfilter` in our nightly conda release (or if you build from source with branch-0.16).

You can do something like:

```
>>> from scipy import signal
>>> import cupy as cp
>>> import cusignal
>>> [b, a] = signal.butter(3, 0.5)
>>> b = cp.asarray(b)
>>> x = cp.random.randn(2**8)
>>> y = cusignal.firfilter(b, x)
```

As a note, we don't currently support butterworth filter design and are dependent on scipy to generate the coefficients before moving them to GPU mem (with `cupy.asarray`).

Comment: Thanks for the response, any update on this?